# Oracle cloud instance cannot communicate with each other via private ip within the same VCN subnet

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am really curious why this happen:
Oracle cloud instances cannot communicate by default with each other via private ip within the same VCN subnet. Is it against intuition as in most cloud providers it is not the case.
By now I didn't find any good or easy way except using Public IP. Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: By communication, mostly I mean ping. There are other ports for other types of communication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emmm my bad. It turns out I need to open ICMP type 8 in security list. BY Default other icmp types are allowed:

[https://docs.public.oneportal.content.oci.oraclecloud.com/en-us/iaas/compute-cloud-at-customer/topics/network/security-rules.htm#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20default%20rule,0.0%2F0%20for%20the%20source](https://docs.public.oneportal.content.oci.oraclecloud.com/en-us/iaas/compute-cloud-at-customer/topics/network/security-rules.htm#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20default%20rule,0.0%2F0%20for%20the%20source).

Answer (score 2):

no communication works from the source server to any target unless you configure the VCN. Please add the ingress and the egress rule for the subnet range using the protocol TCP port 22.